# H2 Not Positioning

Tags: html, css

My H2 is not positioning where I would like it to be and I am not sure why, I have tried postion:absolute and my H2 still does not appear if I add padding-top: 200px I am able to see my H2 but at the very bottom of the page but I can still not position it how I would like to! Im not sure what to do or how to approach this problem.

[This is how I would like my site to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjxp3.png)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!--Banner And Nav-->
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="logo">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
      </ul>
      <h1 class="mainh1">Test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--End Of Banner And Nav-->
  <h2>Hello</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8F3144;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url('logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.mainh1 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  opacity: .5;
}

h2{
  color: black;
  padding-top: 2000px;
}
```

Comment: the reason why your h2 is not showing is because it's behind the banner. you've set your banner to `position: absolute` so that pushes the `h2` up. to see the `h2`, you can add a `margin-top: 300px` to it - this is the same as the height of the banner. then you can increase the margin to place it where you want it.

Comment: i'd recommend you to refactor your html so that the logo is just an `<img>` and not a background image. this way, you won't have to set the banner to `position: absolute`.

Comment: The reason I have the banner to postion:absolute is so it is at the top of the page if i remove it, the banner looks like [https://i.imgur.com/BCPZ9zf.png] (This). I'm not sure how to keep the banner at the top of the page while also being able to position the H2.

Comment: are you talking about that little gap? that's because you have `margin-top:5px` for `.logo`. try using a padding.

Comment: Thank you so much didnt realize at all! Post a answer so I can mark you as correct! :)

Comment: looks like you already marked someone else's answer. oh well. glad you finally have it figured out though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your H2 isn't appearing where you want it to because it doesn't have any positioning set, it's just in the body on the same level as your header div. Since your header div is absolutely positioned, it's removing the natural flow of elements and forcing the h2 to the top.

Drop the position: absolute from your header div, and wrap your subheader in its own div, like:

```
.subheader {
  width: 100%;
}

.subheader h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
```

The white-space that gets created at the top is because of margin-top in your .logo class, either change it to padding-top or (preferably) use an img tag rather than setting background-image.

https://jsfiddle.net/50p420x8/5/